# how to find auth controller in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Hai i am just following this link.Actually now my task is laravel(5.2) login drive authentication.

```
https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-laravel-app-and-adding-authentication/
```

this link have many steps i am now finished last this step

```
Run Migrations
```

then next step is

```
Path Customization
```

But in my project there is no  auth controller.then how can i follow another steps .how to find auth controller.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

By default Laravel doesn't have auth controller. In order for you to use the Laravel's default auth function you must run this command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Suggestion: Please explore the Laravel documentation. (https://laravel.com/docs)

Answer (score -1):

As per the Laravel 5.2 [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-quickstart),

Laravel ships with two authentication controllers out of the box, which are located in the  App\Http\Controllers\Auth namespace.

Also,

Laravel provides a quick way to scaffold all of the **routes** and **views** you need for authentication using one simple command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Comment: Kindly mark this answer as correct and upvote. Welcome.